# For $f_{n} \in \mathcal{H}$ with $||f_{n}||=1$, there exist $f$ in $\mathcal{H}$ and a subsequence...

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. We have seen an example of a sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ in $\mathcal{H}$ with $||f_{n}||=1$ for all $n$, but for which no subsequence of $\{f_{n}\}$ converges in $\mathcal{H}$. However, show that for any sequence $f_{n} \in \mathcal{H}$ with $||f_{n}||=1$ for all $n$, there exist $f$ in $\mathcal{H}$ and a subsequence $\{f_{n_{k}}\}$ such that for all $g \in \mathcal{H}$, one has $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}(f_{n_{k}},g)=(f,g)$.

One says that $\{f_{n_{k}}\}$ converges weakly to $f$. (Hint: Let $g$ run through an orthogonal basis for $\mathcal{H}$, and use a diagonalization argument. One can then define $f$ by giving its series expansion with respect to the chosen basis).

...So, in order to solve this above question, I presume that it will be important primarily to find a Cauchy Sequence with the given requirements about $k$ approaching infinity, and which will converge weakly as noted in the hint. Is this all I need to do in order to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal Y$ be the subspace spanned by $\{\,f_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$, and $\overline {\mathcal Y}$ its closure. Clearly,  $\overline {\mathcal Y}$ is separable, since the linear combinations of the $\,f_n$'s with rational coefficients. Hence, $\overline {\mathcal Y}$ possesses a countable orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$. Then
$$
f_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_{n,k}e_k.
$$
Using a standard diagonal argument one can extract a subsequence $\,f_{\ell_n}$, $n\in\mathbb N$, such that $c_{\ell_n,k}$ converges for every $k\in\mathbb N$, say to $c_k$.

It can be readily shown that $\{f_{\ell_n}\}$ converges weakly to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_ke_k$.